# Unity - Gradle Build error : Could not resolve all files for configuration ':releaseCompileClasspath'

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, facebook-unity-sdk

I am developing a game for Android mobile phones on Unity. I recently updated my facebook SDK , due to merge conflicts when building the app caused by the extra libraries that had to be added to the project by the Play Services Resolver I had to edit my Gradle.properties file to look like below.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M
 android.useAndroidX=true
 android.enableJetifier=true
```

I did this mainly cause some of the support libraries were the cause of the merge conflicts. But now I keep getting the following error and I do not know how to fix it. I have tried reimporting the SDK several times but I still get the same problem. I have also tried asking on the Unity forums but I have received no responses yet. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 * What went wrong:
     Execution failed for task ':preReleaseBuild'.
     > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':releaseCompileClasspath'.
        > Failed to transform artifact 'com.android.support.support-v4-27.0.2.aar (:com.android.support.support-v4-27.0.2:)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-manifest}
           > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: D:\Unity\Projects\Mzito-NewBG\2017.3\Mzito - Unity 2018.1.2f1 - GameTrove\Mzito\Temp\gradleOut\libs\com.android.support.support-v4-27.0.2.aar.
              > Failed to transform 'D:\Unity\Projects\Mzito-NewBG\2017.3\Mzito - Unity 2018.1.2f1 - GameTrove\Mzito\Temp\gradleOut\libs\com.android.support.support-v4-27.0.2.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.v4' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
```

Comment: Can you try android.jetifier.blacklist = com.android.support.support-v4-27.0.2.*\\.aar

Comment: I will try this and let you know if it works .

Comment: tried it , The error is exactly the same tried it , Added what you mentioned like so  `writer.WriteLine("android.jetifier.blacklist = com.android.support.support - v4 - 27.0.2.*\\.aar"); `

Comment: Hi, I'm facing same issue. Any news or solution found? Resolving android libraries didn't do anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

go to Assets\Plugins\Android and remove all content then
in unity editor in Assets menu go to Play Service Resolver(or external play resolver) >Android Resolver>Resolve
now everyThing is oK!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, I've fixed it with :

1. Assets
2. Play Service Resolver
3. Android resolver
4. force resolve

Answer (score -1):

1. Right click on assets folder
2. Select **Play Service Resolver**
3. Android resolver
4. Resolve

It will fix the problem but make sure your java environment variable is setup    otherwise it might not work

[image]

Comment: Tired this a couple of times but it never fixed the error I get.